# Is using MySQL table with parameter type and parameter value columns clear?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table with cases, but each case could have filled different parameters. So I think it is not the best solution to arrange the table such like this (e.g. - there will be much more parametters in real):

**`case`**

```
+----+-------+--------+-------+------------+-------+
| id | label | color  | count | time       | valid |
+----+-------+--------+-------+------------+-------+
| 1  | abcd  | NULL   | 4     | 2013-01-15 | 0     |
| 2  | efgh  | NULL   | NULL  | 2012-12-22 | NULL  |
| 3  | ijkl  | fa8ee0 | NULL  | NULL       | 1     |
| 4  | mnop  | NULL   | 1     | NULL       | 1     |
| ...
```

That contains lot of *NULL* values.

There is another solution, where exists related table `case_params` and its concept is like this:

```
`case`                      `case_params`
+----+-------+              +---------+------------+-------------+
| id | label |              | case_id | param_type | param_value |
+----+-------+              +---------+------------+-------------+
| 1  | abcd  |              | 1       | count      | 4           |
| 2  | efgh  |              | 1       | time       | 2013-01-15  |
| 3  | ijkl  |              | 1       | valid      | 0           |
| 4  | mnop  |              | 2       | time       | 2012-12-22  |
| ...                       | 3       | color      | fa8ee0      |
                            | ...
```

But there evolves the problem with column `param_value` - I could set it as *VARCHAR(32)*, and make trigger which controls every parametter type if its value is correct. But I'm not sure if this is clear solution...

How would **you** solve problem like this? Thx

*sorry when bad english, not native speaker*

Comment: That's a design pattern that's been discussed before (I wish I could remember its name...). It's generally considered a bad idea because there's no way to keep data integrity.

Comment: The answer is very dependent on the concrete problem. It depends on the number of rows a value will be NULL and if several columns are have sort of logical relationship to each other... Sometimes I use nullable columns, sometimes I decide to do it another way.

Comment: There is really lot of kinds of params - actually there is about 60 columns at now (and lot of them remains NULL). Can anyone remember what design pattern solves these relations, please?